# Pandas groupby by category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to group by category

I have this DF(for ex)

```
Period     val2       val3
1         5546708.53    19741660.61
1         5235399.56    13022005.11
2         2294129.82    7336506.28
3         4888151.37    11870210.71
4         1463851.95    8057862.59
5         1733743.17    5131406.15
5         1682831.20    11953188.47
6         2334756.66    8721801.29
7         1011877.55    5565875.39
8         2171051.93    8348294.45
8         797894.95 7218259.63
9         1005890.25    5085592.10
```

And I want to group by Period (1-3 is the first group, 4-6 is the second, 7-9 is the third)
result

```
Period     val2       val3
1         sum(1)      sum(2)
4         sum(3)      sum(4)
7         sum(5)      sum(6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.cut` to get the buckets:

```
periods = pd.cut(df.Period, bins=[0,3,6,9])
(df.groupby(periods,as_index=False)
   .agg({'Period':'min', 'val2':'sum', 'val3':'sum'})
)
```

Output:

```
   Period         val2         val3
0       1  17964389.28  51970382.71
1       4   7215182.98  33864258.50
2       7   4986714.68  26218021.57
```